# Creating a list from a for loop

Tags: list, loops, for-loop, arraylist, nested-loops

I have attempted to change my code several times to create an array of the required values of S.

```
import math as math

def trap(f,a,b):
    return ( f(a) + f(b) ) / 2 * (b-a)

a = 0
b = 2
n_vals = [2**p for p in range (0,21)]
h_vals = [(b-a)/n for n in n_vals]

f= lambda x: math.exp(x)+x**2
for n,h in zip(n_vals,h_vals):
    S = 0
    for k in range(n):
        thisA = a+k*h
        thisB = a+(k+1)*h
        S += trap(f,thisA,thisB)
 
    print(f"Integral  for {n} partitions = {S}")
```

Is there a way to produce a list that contains the sequence of the values of S:

```
I = [12.38905609893065, 9.91280987792437, 9.271610109481282, ...]
```

Comment: Did you just want to ignore the `n` partition value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can initialize a list and append to it at each iteration of the outer loop:

```
import math as math

def trap(f,a,b):
    return ( f(a) + f(b) ) / 2 * (b-a)

a = 0
b = 2
n_vals = [2**p for p in range (0,21)]
h_vals = [(b-a)/n for n in n_vals]

f= lambda x: math.exp(x)+x**2
output = []

for n,h in zip(n_vals,h_vals):
    S = 0
    for k in range(n):
        thisA = a+k*h
        thisB = a+(k+1)*h
        S += trap(f,thisA,thisB)

    print(f"Integral  for {n} partitions = {S}")
    output.append(S)

print(output)
```

Comment: I only want the values of S that correspond to my n